# Ruby Gems getting out of hand

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

So I've recently been having a lot of trouble with my Ruby gems, such as: not being able to uninstall them because they're set to "default", my Bundler version showing as 2.2.9 even after I've uninstalled it, 2.2.9 being installed in the 2.2.7 directory, seeing "bundler" in 3 different directories on my machine, etc.

I would like to:
a) start from scratch by deleting ALL gems and gem folders on my machine (haven't found a way to do that)
b) prevent this from happening again (basically advice)

Some guidance on this would be VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `rbenv` you should find all versions in `~/.rbenv/versions` by default (whatever `$RBENV_ROOT` refers to), and can delete them there.

Depending on OS you may also have a system Ruby installed, which you probably shouldn't mess with.

Comment: I have a lot of gems listed as "default" and therefore can't uninstall them - so I'm going to uninstall rbenv completely, including deleting the entire ~/.rbenv directory, and see where I'm at. I *think* any other gems would be for the OS (will leave that alone).

Answer (score 0):

constant

```
RUBY_VERSION
```

"#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"

or

```
RUBY_DESCRIPTION
```

or gem env